# system slows down after returning from sleep

Tags: suspend, swap, 20.04, intel-atom

I have a 2gb RAM / Atom Z3735F / Ubuntu 20.04 machine . My system slows down after waking up from a sleep . Putting CPU governor in performance mode didn't solve the issue . What i have noticed is after returning from sleep state my swap is almost filled out (1.1G/1.3G) and closing every program reduced the swap usage to 600 mb but it didn't went further down . Any help ?

**swapon -show**

```
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file            4194300 780864  -2
/dev/zram0                              partition       524284  524216  100
```

**grep -i swap /etc/fstab**

```
/dev/zram0              none swap sw,pri=32767 0 0
/swapfile    none    swap    defaults,pri=-3      0   0
```

**free -h**

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          1.9Gi       1.2Gi        89Mi       316Mi       607Mi       212Mi
Swap:         4.5Gi       1.3Gi       3.2Gi
```

**top**

[image]

**[After 1 year]**

edit : eventually I moved to openSUSE TW with KDE Plasma. Cannot reproduce this issue there.

Comment: i think unusually higher amounts of swap usage only after returning from sleep is causing the slow down .

Comment: It's purely because of your 2G RAM limit, and running full Ubuntu. Consider Xubuntu or Lubuntu, as per my answer. Nothing more to troubleshoot.

Comment: @heynnema ok thanks  . Concluding that increasing swap by couple of gigs solved the issue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Let's create a swap file of bigger size  : -***

disable swap and remove existing swap file first

```
sudo swapoff -a && sudo rm /swapfile
```

Start by creating a file which will be used for swap:

```
sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

To make the change permanent open the `/etc/fstab` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

and paste the following line:

```
/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
```

*You can also enable zram which will make your low memory system even faster by doing these steps :-*

Open a terminal window and create a new file with the command:

```
sudo nano /etc/modules-load.d/zram.conf
```

In that file, add the word:

```
zram
```

Save and close the file.

Next, create a second new file with the command:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/zram.conf
```

In that file, paste the line:

```
options zram num_devices=1
```

Save and close the file.

Next, we need to configure the size of the zRAM partition. Create a new file with the command:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-zram.rules
```

In that file, paste the following (modifying the disksize attribute to fit your needs):

```
KERNEL=="zram0", ATTR{disksize}="512M",TAG+="systemd"
```

Save and close the file.

open your `fstab` file with this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

and add this line to the bottom:

```
/dev/zram0 none swap defaults 0 0
```

In order for zRAM to run, we need to create a systemd unit file. Create this file with the command:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/zram.service
```

In that file, paste the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Swap with zram
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot 
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStartPre=/sbin/mkswap /dev/zram0
ExecStart=/sbin/swapon -p 100 /dev/zram0
ExecStop=/sbin/swapoff /dev/zram0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Save and close the file. Enable the new unit with the command:

```
sudo systemctl enable zram
```

Reboot the machine.

For more info refer to this article on techrepublic.com: [How to enable the zram module for faster swapping on Linux](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-the-zram-module-for-faster-swapping-on-linux/)

Comment: Implementing zram on a 2G RAM Ubuntu 20.04 system will only **decrease** available RAM, and **increase** swapping.

Comment: @heynnema oh ! ... but now i'm able to open more number of tabs in firefox and i can even open libreoffice with 6 to 7 firefox tabs . previously this was not the case .when opening 4 or 5 tabs loading time was a pain , now that the pain is reduced much and system feels a little bit snappier . Dont know about the technical side of thing tho , this answer is purely based on my experience . should i remove the Accepted answer tick ?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `swapon -show` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `free -h` and `top`.

Comment: @heynnema done .

Comment: In reviewing that info, I stand by my earlier comment about "Implementing zram on a 2G RAM Ubuntu 20.04 system will only **decrease** available RAM, and **increase** swapping".

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you've got a "2gb RAM / Atom Z3735F / Ubuntu 20.04 machine". You should really be running Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

However, let's try enlarging your swap, and see if it helps.

If `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` returns this...

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

Then do this...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 2G RAM and 4G swap
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Comment: yeah , increasing swap usage to 4 gigs from 2 gb helped alot . it turns out that after a suspend the swap is not getting released properly . Now swap usage strikes 1.2 gb with just 2 Firefox tabs after waking up from suspend .

Comment: @heynneme "swap usage strikes 1.2 gb with just 2 Firefox tabs after waking up from suspend" : is this normal ?

Comment: @Afsal  Yes. Swap usually never goes back to zero.